# Calculating the normalization constant for a wavefunction

Tags: physics

How can I compute the normalization constant for a quantum mechanics wave-function, like $\Psi(x) = N \exp(-\lambda x^2/2)$ by using *Mathematica*? (The normalization constant is $N$).

Comment: The normalization is given in terms of the integral of the absolute square of the wave function. You can calculate this using `Integrate`.

Comment: Caveat: the normalization constant **in mathematica** is most certainly **not** the reserved symbol `N` ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First define the wave function as

```
Ψ[x_] := n Exp[-λ x^2/2];
```

Then you define your normalization condition

```
condition = 
 Integrate[Ψ[x]^2, {x, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> λ > 0] == 1

(* (n^2 Sqrt[π])/Sqrt[λ] == 1 *)

Solve[condition, n]
(* {{n -> -(λ^(1/4)/π^(1/4))}, {n -> λ^(1/4)/π^(1/4)}} *)
```

Either of these works, the wave function is valid regardless of overall phase.

Edit: You should only do the above code if you **can** do the integral by hand, because everyone should go through the trick of solving the [Gaussian integral](http://www.umich.edu/~chem461/Gaussian%20Integrals.pdf) for themselves at least once.

Comment: At least *once*?! At least *ten* times! And then there's the differentiate with respect to a parameter trick, and how to generalize to multi-dimensional Gaussians, etc.

Comment: @Jason B : The link requires authentication. It's okay, though, as I was just wondering how to do this by using mathematica; The textbook I am following covers doing it by hand pretty well. I figured it out later on on my own, but your solution is way more elegant than mine (you define a function, which is less messy)! Thanks! :-D